# Suppressing warning outputs in JMeter

Tags: cookies, warnings, jmeter

Using JMeter, I am running a few different thread groups with some containing different HTTP Cookie Managers. I have a default HTTP Cookie Manager that encompasses all Thread Groups that should be used when a HTTP Cookie Manager doesn't exist for the specific thread group.

The test runs fine, but my log is cluttered with messages like this: 
`jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Existing CookieManager HTTP Cookie Manager superseded by HTTP Cookie Manager`, which I don't care for.

Is there a way to surpress warnings in the log, such as this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the log level to ERROR in the JMeter properties file. It is 'INFO' by default.

```
Go to JMETER_HOME/bin
Open jmeter.properties
Update log_level.jmeter=INFO
```

But if you want to avoid the particular WARN, 
Do you also have HTTP Request Defaults in your test? If yes, Disable 'concurrent pool' in that. This should avoid the errors you see now in the log.